# sql sum + varchar

Tags: sql

I have varchar type column in my sql table(SQL 2008) for storing student marks. If I store only the marks I can calculate the sum of marks by casting the column to integer.

But I need to store `Absent` for absentees. And now, its showing error in that `Absent` when casting to integer and sum the value, after inserting `Absent`.

Is it possible to sum only the marks, and excluding the `Absent`?I tried like this

```
select sum(cast(Marks as integer))
from Results    
group by Marks
```

Comment: That's a really bad design - I would use a `Marks INT` column, and leave it `NULL` when the student was absent. That way, you can (a) easily sum up your marks (since it's already `INT`), and those entries with `NULL` are those where the student was absent - no need to store that as a `Varchar` column, really ....

Comment: You are right marc_s, but I need to handle Absentees also, thats what. anyhow am allowing null also

Comment: `Marks IS NULL` --> absentee - doesn't that work?? Or if not: add a `BIT` column `IsAbsentee` - but **don't** store something like this as a `varchar` !

Comment: fine, thanks for ur valuable suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add `Group by` Clause.

No other columns in Select other than column used in Aggregate function then no need to have GROUP BY.

```
select sum(cast(Marks as integer))
from Results    
where Marks <>'Absent'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use an integer column for `Marks` and you should have a column of its own for Absent.

To fix your current situation you can use a `case` statement.

```
select sum(case Marks when 'Absent' then 0 else Marks end)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(cast(Marks as integer))
from Results
where Marks <> 'Absent'
```

Just add a where clause!

Comment: great, but its not summming the value

Comment: I just added a where clause to your original query - it would probably work fine by simply removing the `group by` clause. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

use decode function as -

```
select sum(decode(Marks, 'Absent', 0, cast(Marks as integer)))
```

Comment: I thought to do like this, but I didn't know how to do, thanks for ur response abhinav, I'll check it

Comment: its showing error like "'decode' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: sql 2008, Romil's idea is working for me, sorry thats my mistake only I just edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
select sum(cast(Marks as integer))
from Results
where Marks <> 'Absent'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the absent is `Absent` in the column.
Try this -

```
select sum(IF(Marks = 'Absent', 0, cast(Marks as integer))) -- MySQL
select sum(decode(Marks, 'Absent', 0, cast(Marks as integer))) -- Oracle
from Results    
group by Marks;
```

OR

```
select sum(cast(Marks as integer))
from Results
where Marks <> 'Absent'
group by Marks
```

Comment: thanks Juniad, am using Sql 2008 and in ur 2nd solution without using group by ,its working

Answer (score 1):

Wow, my preferred solution in SQL Server would simply be:

```
select sum(case when isnumeric(Marks) = 1 then cast(Marks as Integer) end)
from Results
```

Or, equivalently:

```
select cast(Marks as Integer)
from Results
where isnumeric(Marks) = 1
```

The group by is unnecessary, unless you are trying to produce a histogram.

By the way, the above is still prone to error, because floating point numbers cannot safely be converted to integers.  You might prefer:

```
select cast(sum(case when isnumeric(Marks) = 1 then cast(Marks as float) end) as int)
from Results
```

Comment: This works the best since the other answers assume the only non-integer is "Absent" . If there are numerous non-integers then the other answers are tedious.